# How to use defined String in for loop in Python

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I have a question regarding for loop and string in Python.

I have defined 2 vars for configuration during json format -

```
new_repository_config_0 = {
    "name": "bla777",
    "online": "true",
    "storage": {
        "blobStoreName": "nexus-blobstore",
        "strictContentTypeValidation": "true",
        "writePolicy": "allow_once"
    },
    "maven": {
        "versionPolicy": "SNAPSHOT",
        "layoutPolicy": "STRICT"
    }
}

new_repository_config_1 = {
    "name": "bla888",
    "online": "true",
    "storage": {
        "blobStoreName": "nexus-blobstore",
        "strictContentTypeValidation": "true",
        "writePolicy": "allow_once"
    },
    "maven": {
        "versionPolicy": "SNAPSHOT",
        "layoutPolicy": "STRICT"
    }
}
```

Also I have defined a function, and I want to use those conf vars in main.

I want to do it this way -

```
repositories = get_resource(config=config, api_type='repositories')
for i in range(1):
    string = 'config.new_repository_config_%d' % (i,)
    print (string)
    if string['name'] not in \
            [repository['name'] for repository in repositories]:
        create_repo(
           config=config, repository=string)
```

Basically, the if statement line, once must be -

> if config.new_repository_config_0['name']

And the second time, it must be -

> if config.new_repository_config_1['name']

But since, I'm making conversion to String, I'm getting this error -

> "if string['name'] not in \ TypeError: string indices must be
> integers"

Is there a way to solve it in Python?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a `list` to hold your config objects instead of separate variables. Then index into that list. Or a `dict`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/843953

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to iterate over your `dict`s?:

```py
repositories = get_resource(config=config, api_type='repositories')
for string in [config.new_repository_config_0, config.new_repository_config_1]:
    print (string)
    if string['name'] not in \
            [repository['name'] for repository in repositories]:
        create_repo(
           config=config, repository=string)
```

Comment: Yeah, but what I will have not 2, but 10 or 100 conf files, is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: How will you know that you have 100 conf files?

Comment: And thought to make config.new_repository_config_X , and adding 1 every time to an X.
And if there won't be any files left, it will quit.

Comment: Or to define it in range